# How do I find out how to say "I speak Dutch?" in Netherlands?

Tags: netherlands, dutch-language

I'm trying to figure out how someone in the Netherlands would say their own language. What is Dutch called in Dutch, in other words?

When I go to Google Translate and type "Dutch" in the English box, "Nederlands" appears in the  Dutch box. Is the country name and the language the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The country is called *Nederland*, the language is called *Nederlands*.

*Ik spreek Nederlands* (literally: *I speak Dutch*) is correct.

Comment: IMO, it would be better if you please include the English transliteration with that.

Comment: @kmonsoor I considered that implied from the question, but OK.

Comment: BTW: This is also correct in Belgium (where the Northern part, Flanders, speaks Dutch - although the spoken language sounds different).